# Implementation of M method Of Simplex For LP in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, matlab

I have to solve LP problem in JAVA and have to keep track of iterations number to solve LP by simplex method . I have used MATLAB for this purpose . But matlab initially finds an suitable vertex and starts from that vertex . So the iterations number to solve LP by Simplex is not correct .

Hence I have started using [Simplex.java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/65reductions/Simplex.java.html) . But it supports only solution of Lp problem for less than constraint .

I have heard that "greater than " constraint can be handled by M method . Can you help me by providing implementation of M method in JAVA . ?

I have to submit my thesis within 2 days . I have made an algorithm for my thesis . I have to check my algorithm by solving LP method by solving this problem and keep tracking no of iterations to solve LP problem .

Comment: If Simplex.java can handle less than constraints and you need to handle greater than, you just need to modify your constraints. For example,
-1x + 5y > 0 becomes
1x -5y < 0

Comment: But the above can not handle the constraint like this : 
$ -x+5y \le -30 $